# How to bind a list of lists in OnPost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and trying to bind this property, but when I put a breakpoint at the `OnPost` function, I get an empty list.

I am using netcoreapp3.1

###### Edit.cshtml.cs

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<List<Beam>> Beams { get; set; } 
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

###### Edit.cshtml

```
<form method="post" >

@for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    @for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamLayerName" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j+1) Layer Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamLayerName" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamLayerName" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamDepth" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j+1) Depth </label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamDepth" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamDepth" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamWidth" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j+1) Width</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamWidth" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamWidth" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamTopLevel" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j+1) Top Level </label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamTopLevel" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i].ElementAt(j).BeamTopLevel" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
 }

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save changes</button>
```

###### Beam Class

```
public class Beam
{
    public int BeamId { get; set; }
    public string BeamLayerName { get; set; }
    public double BeamTopLevel { get; set; }
    public double BeamDepth { get; set; }
    public double BeamWidth { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The model binder does not recognize the `Beams[i].ElementAt(j)` syntax. So firstly, try changing it to `Beams[i][j]` everywhere. Since it is a list of lists, this should work.

If this is not possible or it doesn't work, try using an editor template. An editor template is a better option and the recommended approach as it is well-suited for such scenarios.

#### Creating an Editor Template:

1. Create a `Shared` folder inside your `Pages` folder if it is not already there.
2. Inside this `Shared` folder, create a folder called `EditorTemplates`.
3. Inside `EditorTemplates`, create a Razor view with the same name as the model. Here, it is `Beam`, so name the file as `Beam.cshtml`.

*Your file path should look like this: `Pages/Shared/Beam.cshtml`*

4. In the `Beam.cshtml` file, add the `@model` directive as `Beam` and then add the input fields:

```
@model Beam
<input type="hidden" asp-for="BeamId">
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="BeamLayerName" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam Layer Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input asp-for="BeamLayerName" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="BeamLayerName" class="alert-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="BeamDepth" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam Depth </label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input asp-for="BeamDepth" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="BeamDepth" class="alert-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="BeamWidth" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam Width</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input asp-for="BeamWidth" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="BeamWidth" class="alert-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="BeamTopLevel" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam Top Level </label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input asp-for="BeamTopLevel" class="form-control">
        <span asp-validation-for="BeamTopLevel" class="alert-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an editor template for a single beam. Now to reuse this editor template for each item in your list, you will have to use the `Html.EditorFor()` method in your `Edit.cshtml`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Beams[i])
}
```

This is all you need. As you might have noticed, you don't even need the inner loop.
The only down-side here is you cannot use indexes like `Beam @(j+1)`. One solution maybe to create a `BeamViewModel` to include the index and then use a `List<List<BeamViewModel>>`

Similarly, there are display templates which help reuse a template for displaying a collection of objects with `Html.DisplayFor()`. More on this [here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your help [Amal K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11455105/amal-k) , I used this code and it works well.

```
<form method="post">

@for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    @for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamLayerName" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j + 1) Layer Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamLayerName" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i][j].BeamLayerName" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamDepth" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j + 1) Depth </label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamDepth" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i][j].BeamDepth" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamWidth" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j + 1) Width</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamWidth" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i][j].BeamWidth" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamTopLevel" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Beam @(j + 1) Top Level </label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input asp-for="Beams[i][j].BeamTopLevel" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="Beams[i][j].BeamTopLevel" class="alert-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save changes</button>
```